# Google wants to verify my adress because of AdMob

Tags: admob, ads, verification

Google wants to verify my adress because of AdMob. They want to send a PIN number in a traditional letter on adress which I have set. The problem is that account adress is false. I have a question: Will they send that letter even if I did not clicked the "Send me PIN" button? And if they will send that letter will it contain my account password? Please help:)

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not support for products you use. Please read the rules.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a product support question, and not a programming question within the scope defined by the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

AdMob send your PIN by standard mail several days after your account balance reaches the verification threshold.

The letter contains only PIN that can only used by your AdMob account.

**If you haven’t received your first PIN?** You can [request additional](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3198657) PINs.

Before requesting a new PIN, correct your [payment address](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2772304).